# AWS CDK(Pipeline)- Using Elastic Client in the lambda code encounter error TS1192: Module '"http"' has no default export

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Below is the error occurs in pipeline build phrase

```
found 0 vulnerabilities

[Container] 2023/11/01 09:50:54.339059 Running command npm run build

> php_call@0.1.0 build
> tsc

**node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/connection/HttpConnection.d.ts(3,8): error TS1192: Module '"/codebuild/output/src1897116248/src/node_modules/hpagent/index"' has no default export.
node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/connection/HttpConnection.d.ts(4,8): error TS1192: Module '"http"' has no default export.
node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/connection/HttpConnection.d.ts(5,8): error TS1192: Module '"https"' has no default export.
**
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.403663 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 2
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.407098 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.407124 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 2
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.453719 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.455394 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.455406 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.560643 Expanding base directory path: cdk.out
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.562579 Assembling file list
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.562592 Expanding cdk.out
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.564242 Skipping invalid file path cdk.out
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.564291 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/11/01 09:51:08.564300 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching base directory path found for cdk.out
```

I have used AWS CDK to set up a pipeline and have used a nodeJSfunction to create a lambda stack.
but I am stuck in the build pharse with this error... Could anyone help?

Below is my source code
Lambda Stack

```
    const db = new NodejsFunction(this, 'phpcall', {
      bundling: {
        nodeModules: ['axios', 'crypto', '@elastic/elasticsearch']
      }

    })
```

import statement in Lambda code

```
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch'
```

Comment: I have also try "import * as elasticClient from '@elastic/elasticsearch' " but this is also doesn't work

Comment: I fixed above issue by putting the following inside the tsconfig.json file:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true
    ...
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above issue by putting the following inside the `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true
    ...
  }
}
```